# Cannot load the nodes jTree using Java netbeans

Tags: java, swing, jtree

this is the first time i am using jtree using java. but i couldn't load it when i tried load it it shown as blank.i dont know how to load it.what i tried so far i attached below.please give me the solution for it thanks. JTree name is jTree1

```
DefaultTreeModel root1;
     DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root"); 
        public void Load()
        {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode vegetableNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Vegetables");
            vegetableNode.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Capsicum"));
            vegetableNode.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Carrot"));
            vegetableNode.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Tomato"));
            vegetableNode.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Potato"));
            DefaultMutableTreeNode fruitNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Fruits");
            fruitNode.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Banana"));
            fruitNode.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Mango"));
            fruitNode.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Apple"));
            fruitNode.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Grapes"));
            fruitNode.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Orange")); 
            root.add(vegetableNode);
            root.add(fruitNode); 
            root1 = (DefaultTreeModel)jTree1.getModel();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the tree to the root, then add the tree to the `JTree`:

```
root1 = (DefaultTreeModel)jTree1.getModel();
```

To:

```
root1.setRoot(root);
jTree1.setModel(root1);
```

See the [`setModel()` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#setModel(javax.swing.tree.TreeModel)).

Comment: root1 = (DefaultTreeModel)jTree1.getModel();
        jTree1.setModel(root);   i wrote it but error displayed this line of the code

Comment: Oops, I made an error - please try this slight modification.